# Using the words 'wrong' and 'amiss' in American English

Tags: word-usage

In the sentences bellow, in my view the versions with the word 'amiss' sound incorrect or at least unidiomatic:

> - What’s wrong?
> - What’s amiss?

---

> - Is something wrong?
> - Is something amiss?

---

> - Is there something wrong?
> - Is there something amiss?

---

> - What’s wrong with the car today? → Nothing is wrong with the car.
> - What’s amiss with the car today? → Nothing is amiss with the car.

---

> - Something is wrong with my foot.
> - Something is amiss with my foot.

Comment: it's archaic - but can be used to add quirkiness or humour in modern parlance. I wouldn't use it if my foot hurt, though [unless I was an android in the light-hearted bit of the movie, just before the monsters attack]; the rest I would, in the right circumstance.

Comment: also, "something's amiss" (or "there's something amiss") is a fairly well known idiom that people may use, usually humorously, when the situation they are in feels 'wrong'.

Comment: agree @sgroves - it's better than "It's quiet, sarge, too quiet."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These uses of *amiss* are all "correct" and all idiomatic. But *amiss* is a fairly 'literary' word which is not heard much in ordinary conversation today, so using it will stand out as somewhat humorous or affected.